# Solr sort in correct alphabetical order

Tags: sorting, solr

I have an issue - its needed to sort SOLR results in correct alphabetical order if there are both upper and lowercase values in response.
Now, using

```
<field name="somefield"  type="text_general"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/> 

<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I can easily get smth like this

```
aaa
AAA
BBB
bbb
BBB
DDD
ddd
```

like there is no priority between upper and lowercase letters.

But its needed to get like this:

```
aaa
AAA
bbb
BBB
BBB
ddd
DDD
```

How to do such sorting correctly?

Comment: Which version are you using? I tried to reproduce your problem with Solr 5.4.1, but when I tell Solr to sort on that text-field the documents are sorted in the correct order.

Comment: @cuh Thank you.  I am using 5.4.0. Do you obtain exactly results as needed? Can you provide your configuration of field and type?

Comment: @cuh Because I currently try on a new core for field title_t (text_general) and received such results/ Take a look on ddd and DDD section
`      {
        "title_t": "AAA"
      },
      {
        "title_t": "aaa"
      },
      {
        "title_t": "aaa"
      },
      {
        "title_t": "BBB"
      },
      {
        "title_t": "ddd"
      },
      {
        "title_t": "DDD"
      },
      {
        "title_t": "ddd"
      }`

Answer (score 1):

In 99% of the cases, you don't want to sort on the tokenized field. Because when you end up with 5 tokens, which of them are you sorting by?

However, if you want to lowercase, it could be a tokenized field, just with [KeywordTokenizer](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#KeywordTokenizerFactory) and LowercaseFilter. That way you always get one token and it is lower case. Use copyField from the original field if you still want to search the original field with synonyms, etc. Don't have to store the copy, sorting uses indexed representation only.

Also, docValues are good for sorting.